# Undefined reference to `atexit'

Tags: c++

when compiling C++ project,

I got an error for this:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0xc): undefined reference to `__libc_csu_fini'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x11): undefined reference to `__libc_csu_init'

....: undefined reference to `atexit'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

this is the code:

```
std::atexit(myExitFunction);
```

the myExitFunction has been declared well. Why would it complains about atexit?

Comment: Could you edit and add more code about this problem?

Comment: yes, I have updated more error details

Comment: I don't know if you have a code template in you project, but maybe this can help you:  http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1388438

Comment: What is the compilation command line of your code? Are you sure it is being compiled as C++?

Answer (score 0):

This is a linking error message. The compiler successfully found the *declaration* of `std::atexit()`, but the linker can't find any compiled *definition* of this function.

Try to link your code by adding this argument to the linker :

```
-stdlib=libc++
```

Comment: I think I have to ask you another question. I am using cmake to compile my C++ project. I m quite new with it. where should I place that argument? thanks in advance

Comment: I managed to use: set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_INIT "-Wall -stdlib=libc++") but the problem persits

Comment: I'm not a regular user of `cmake`, but according to [a post on its mailing list](http://www.cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2006-October/011517.html), you should also set `CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS`.